# VBA Find row number through loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have some code below that loops through each row in Column L and runs the script below on each row that a hyperlink is present in Col L, the code works great, it opens and scrapes the data fine, but I would like to add values to other columns based on the row that is being processed.

```
Public Sub CallRangeL_Urls()
   Dim i As Range
   For Each i In Sheet1.Range("L4:L200")
    ImportData i.Value
   Next i
End Sub

Public Sub ImportData(ByVal urlToOpen As String)

...

With CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
.Open "GET", urlToOpen False 'Cell that contains hyperlink
.send
HTML_Content.body.innerHTML = .responseText
End With

' Code here to scrape

'Add Value to Sheet1

Sheets(1).Range("E4").Value = rng1.Offset(0, 1)
Else

Sheets(1).Range("E4").Value = 0
End If


End Sub
```

So for example if it's scraping the data from URL located in L4, I would like it to dump the corresponding data into E4, as it shows `Sheets(1).Range("E4").Value = rng1.Offset(0, 1)`

How code I get it to find it's current row or increment it each time? I have tried the following and it doesnt work unfortunately.

```
rowNumber = Sheets(1).Range("L4:L150").Row
Sheets(1).Cells(rowNumber, "E").Value = rng1.Offset(0, 1)
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now it will always put the data in E4, but if you pass the range itself to `ImportData`, you can use offset to find the right row in column E:

in the for loop, call `ImportData i` Instead of `ImportData i.Value`

Change the sub header to:

```
Public Sub ImportData(ByVal urlRange as Range)
```

And instead of `urlToOpen` use `urlRange.value`

When you want to put the value into column E, instead of E4, use `urlRange.Offset(0,-7)`, since E is 7 columns less than column L.

Comment: You sir are an absolute life saver, thank you for your nice and simple solution, this has also helped me understand better/ Thank you